# ValueError while fitting a double-peak log-normal distribution to data

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

Given the following set of data:

```
x=[1.99526231e+08, 7.94328235e+08, 3.16227766e+09, 1.25892541e+10, 5.01187234e+10, 1.99526231e+11, 7.94328235e+11]
y=[0, 0, 0.01, 0.19, 0.09, 0, 0.71]
yerr=[0, 0, 0.00894427, 0.10430724, 0.08049845, 0., 0.171114]
```

I would like to fit a double-peak log-normal distribution function. Here is my try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.array([1.99526231e+08, 7.94328235e+08, 3.16227766e+09, 1.25892541e+10, 5.01187234e+10, 1.99526231e+11, 7.94328235e+11])
y=np.array([0, 0, 0.01, 0.19, 0.09, 0, 0.71])
yerr=np.array([0, 0, 0.00894427, 0.10430724, 0.08049845, 0., 0.171114])

h, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

def PDF(x, A1, B1, A2, B2):
    return (2*np.pi)**(-1/2) * (B1*x)**(-1) * np.exp(-(np.log(x)-A1)**2/(2*B1**2)) + (2*np.pi)**(-1/2) * (B2*x)**(-1) * np.exp(-(np.log(x)-A2)**2/(2*B2**2))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(PDF, x, y, sigma=yerr, p0 = [10.1, 3e10, 11.9, 7e11], bounds=([9.9, 8e9, 11.7, 3e11], [10.3, 5e10, 12.1, 1e12]), method='trf')
xdata = np.array(np.logspace(8.30, 11.90, 1000))
ax.plot(xdata, PDF(xdata, *popt), 'blue',  linestyle = 'solid', label='Best-Fit')
ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr = np.array([0]*7), yerr = yerr, ecolor = 'b', fmt='b.', markersize = '5', elinewidth = 0.25, capsize = 2, linestyle = '')
ax.set_xlim([1e8, 2e12])
ax.set_ylim([-0.03, 0.96])
ax.set_xscale("log", nonposx='clip')
ax.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", direction="in")

h.subplots_adjust(left=0.11, bottom=0.14, right=0.99, top=0.99, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.)
h.text(0.52,0.02,'$x$', fontsize=12, ha='center')
h.text(0.01, 0.52, r'PDF', fontsize=12, va='center', rotation='vertical')
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in h.axes[:-1]], visible=True)
plt.show()
```

And here is the error message I receive which I am not understanding:

```
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:728: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  transform = 1.0 / sigma
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 14, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(PDF, x, y, sigma=yerr, p0 = [10.1, 3e10, 11.9, 7e11], bounds=([9.9, 8e9, 11.7, 3e11], [10.3, 5e10, 12.1, 1e12]), method='trf')
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 762, in curve_fit
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py", line 805, in least_squares
    raise ValueError("Residuals are not finite in the initial point.")
ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.
```

I only anticipate that the number of degrees of freedom are large compared to the available data. Is that right?
[image: Here is the errorbars without the best-fit parametrization]

Comment: your problem is `division by zero` from the `curve_fit()` with `sigma = 0` from `yerr = [0, 0, ....]`

Comment: @DOOM, thank. I also tried to remove zero-values (even though they make sense physically) but the problem is still there.

Comment: /home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:794: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)

Comment: I do not know a priori the best fitting function. This type of mixed model is only my best try. I am just trying to find the best-fitting function. However, I do not know if there is one with fewer parameters.

Comment: the error is not a programming flaw, but more to do with your `input data`. The `Residuals` error is from `least_square` failing to fit the data.

Comment: Visually inspecting scatterplots of both the raw and log-normal data do not appear to suggest to me any fitting function at all. Might you be able to acquire more data to help characterize a potential modeling equation?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, thanks, Unfortunately these are the only available data we have from current simulations and I won't have more data until very later next year. The only constrain is that there are two peaks with the low-end approaching zero.

Comment: plus there are horizontal errorbars too which I have not included. Would that be of any help?

Comment: In that case, ODR might help here. From the scipy.ODR docs at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html "Why Orthogonal Distance Regression (ODR)? Sometimes one has measurement errors in the explanatory (a.k.a., “independent”) variable(s), not just the response (a.k.a., “dependent”) variable(s). "